# How to configure to send email through localhost app server without authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have configured the Rails mailer under config/initializers/ like following:

**/config/initializers/setup_email.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => 'gmail.com',
   :authentication => :plain,
   :user_name=><username>,
   :password=><password>,
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

it works fine, I can send emails and get them received.

But how to configure it to send email from localhost without authentication(without username and password), that's do not use gmail, but send email through the application's local server, how to configure then?

--EDIT---
When using localhost, the error message I got is:

```
Connection refused - connect(2)
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `initialize'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `open'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:127:in `deliver!'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:1967:in `do_delivery'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:401:in `deliver_mail'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/messages.rb:52:in `instrument'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/messages/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/messages.rb:52:in `instrument'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:399:in `deliver_mail'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@myapp/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib/mail/message.rb:228:in `deliver'
/home/user1/myapp/app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:9:in `new_car_messages'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `send_action'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/old_api.rb:75:in `process'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:446:in `process'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:441:in `initialize'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:425:in `new'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/actionmailer-3.0.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:425:in `method_missing'
/home/user1/myapp/config/../lib/my/new_car_sender.rb:7:in `send_email'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `each'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `__send__'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:13:in `each'
/home/user1/myapp/config/../lib/my/new_car_sender.rb:6:in `send_email'
/home/user1/myapp/lib/tasks/new_car_messages.rake:8
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@global/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have set up the local SMTP server then you should just provide connection details for that:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "localhost",
    :port                 => 25
}
```

You should have that in your config/environments/*.rb files.

Comment: No..it does not work for me, I got "Connection refused - connect(2)" error

Comment: Hi, I have put it under config/enviroments/development.rb, but I got the same error from console "Connection refused - connect(2)" :(

Answer (score 3):

In order to send emails you need to setup an smtp server. It could be setup locally or use a remote service like Gmail, SendGrid or Mandrill. In your case I would suggest using [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/).

From the docs:

> ### How
>
> 1. gem install mailcatcher
> 2. mailcatcher
> 3. Go to `http://localhost:1080/`
> 4. Send mail through `smtp://localhost:1025`
>
> ### Rails
>
> To set up your rails app, I recommend adding this to your
>   environments/development.rb:
>
> `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
>   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }`

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing email functionality from localhost then firstly find out if you have sendmail installed and working, if it's not then run this command in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install sendmail

after installing this try sending email.. because the configuration looks fine..

Comment: is 'sudo apt-get install sendmail'

Answer (score 2):

Add the [`letter_opener`](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem to the `development` gem group in `Gemfile`.

Add these lines to `development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost, port: 3000" }
```

and you should see triggered emails pop up in your browser without running an STMP server nor authentication.

Email in Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

adding 'enable_starttls_auto: false' option solved problem for me.

Here is my config (..\config\environments\development.rb):

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:  'localhost',
  port:     25,
  domain:   'exmaple.com',
      enable_starttls_auto: false
}
```

```html
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
Rails 4.2.5`
```

Comment: Thanks John, I upvoted in case anyone had the same problem. This solved it for me. (Rails 3)

Answer (score 0):

And even shorter: 
No entry at all. Both localhost and port number are defaults.

My current configuration in config/development.rb:

```
#config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }
```

I kept it commented to remember where to change when I play around with a remote smtp host.

EDIT (since I don't have reputation enough to comment on the right post):
I saw your comment to the post by @HakonB that you got "Connection refused - connect(2)". Do you have access to the mail server log at localhost? I think you should look there for a hint on how to solve this issue.

Comment: @Mellon, sorry, I was unclear about which log I meant. I was thinking about the mail server log  (/var/log/maillog or something similiar depending on what you are running).
I have spent hours troubleshooting my rails app for errors when sending email, just to find that the mail server rejected.

Comment: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

and then modify the configuration to:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Finally, you will find that most email services will block your host (a policy to avoid spam).